# Python-audiodiff installation

Tags: python-3.x, mutagen

trying to install audio diff for python 3.0 in visual studio code but getting an error message stating no matching distribution found for mutagen==1.21.
I tried installing mutagen 1.21 got installed but still not able to install audiodiff.

Comment: I get a pretty long error message when I try to do the same, looks like they have a syntax error in the code for it: `except EnvironmentError, err:` results in `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

So, looking at [this issue](https://github.com/clee704/audiodiff/issues/1) it looks like these libraries (`mutagenwrapper` and `audiodiff`) are written for Python2 so if you are using Python3 they won't work.

Luckily, it looks like [@SteveClement](https://github.com/SteveClement) has updated them to Python3 himself (thank you to [this comment](https://github.com/clee704/audiodiff/issues/1#issuecomment-761876146) for pointing it out).

So, to install his versions of them:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/SteveClement/mutagenwrapper.git
pip install git+https://github.com/SteveClement/audiodiff.git
```

I can't test these but let me know if this works for you.